# pip wont install anything getting numerous erros etc

Tags: python, django, ssl, pip, installation

So I have python 2.7
have pip installed
pip is upgraded
cant install anything i get all kinds of errors and have tried all kinds of solutions.
why do i have to type: C:\Users\kingj>python -m pip install 
instead of pip install without getting: C:\Users\kingj>pip install
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

everyone else seems to just type pip install etc... i have to do python -m pip install

then when i do do it like that i get this:C:\Users\kingj>python -m pip install django-json
Collecting django-json
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/django-json/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django-json (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for django-json

even though i have tried multiple packages by name and i get only that message?!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your PATH variable isn't pointing to pip correctly. I'm not sure what the correct directory is in Windows as I'm a mac user. But i would start by looking there. Also, it may be worth uninstalling and reinstalling Python. I know there is a checkbox for updating your PATH variable when you do a fresh install of Python. Also, the newest versions of Python ship with pip correctly installed for you. If that is unsuccessful, check here: [How do I install pip on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows)